# Close Modal and scrollToView in Titanium Alloy

Tags: javascript, titanium-alloy

I am trying to set it so that when I close my modal window it changes the page it is going back to using $.viewContainer.scrollToView(2); how can I don this? 
I open my modal using this:

```
$.Login2.addEventListener("click", function() {
    var Login = Alloy.createController('Login').getView();
    Login.open({
        modal : true,
    });
});
```

and inside my modal I close it using this:

```
$.closeLogin.addEventListener("click", function() {
$.Login.close();
});
```

on close I would like it to set the view of scrollableView of the page that opened it to view 2.

Comment: so can't you just call $.viewContainer.scrollToView(2); in the $.closeLogin eventListener?

Comment: No because I get a Cannot call method scrollview of undefined

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to pass a callback to your Login controller which you will then call in your $.closeLogin click eventlistener, e.g.:

Index.js:

```
function doSomething(){
    $.viewContainer.scrollToView(2);
}
$.Login2.addEventListener("click", function() {
    var Login = Alloy.createController('Login', {'cb':doSomething}).getView();
    Login.open({
        modal : true,
    });
});
```

Test.js:

```
var args = arguments[0] || {};

$.closeLogin.addEventListener("click", function() {
    $.Login.close();
    args.cb();
});
```